# First element of imagelist selected

Tags: vb.net, treeview, imagelist

I have an issue with an image List which I use for a treeview that I fill with items. By some properties of these, I select an image from the imageList. 
My problem is that when I load my list of items in the treeview, the first one gets the first image of the imageList and then it gets the image I set.

By reading the documentation, It seems that there is no way to avoid the first element of the imageList to be selected but there must be some kind of trick I can use.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Actually, there is no specific code for this part, I set the property ImageList of the treeview to match with my list of images and It automatically set the ImageIndex and the selectedImageIndex to 0.
Then I use this to set my images when I fill the treeView :
Me.treeView.Nodes.Find("CO", True)(0).Nodes.Add(Key, Text, ImageKey)

Comment: If you want a node to _**not**_ have an image just set `ImageIndex` to -1.

Comment: I tried it, but it resets the imageIndex to 0 just after I set it to -1

Comment: I think some code would help. Specifically this `when I load my list of items in the treeview, the first one gets the first image of the imageList and then it gets the image I set`

Comment: I just solved the problem. It was the ImageIndex and the selectedImageIndex of the treeview which were set to 0 by default. I just set the imageIndex of my treeView like this : 
treeView.ImageIndex = imageList.Images.IndexOfKey(node.FirstNode.ImageKey)
Then I put  the treeView ImageIndex into the selectedImageIndex : 
treeView.SelectedImageIndex = treeView.ImageIndex
And I finally put the first node into my treeView selectedNode :
treeView.SelectedNode = node.FirstNode